# Calling another lemma inside an ensures clause in Dafny

Tags: formal-verification, dafny

Say I have a lemma that takes `x` of type `t` and converts it to `x'`  of type `t'`.

```
lemma convert(x: t) returns (x': t')
    ensures P(x');
{
    ...
}
```

I have another lemma that uses `convert` as a helper method to construct some new object `a'` from `a`, something such as

```
lemma foo(a: s) returns (a': s') 
    ensures a'.x == convert(a.x);
{ 
    ...
    a'.x == convert(a.x);
    ....
}
```

Importantly I want `foo` to ensure that the returned object is constructed correctly, so I want foo to ensure `a'.x == convert(a.x)` . However, dafny does not like this, and will complain with

> Error: expression is not allowed to invoke a method
>   Error: method call is not allowed to be used in an expression context

I see that this stems from the fact that method calls can't appear in expressions. How do I achieve what I desire then?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to make `convert` a function instead of a lemma. Properties of `convert` can be proved using a separate lemma.